Cannot deploy firebase functions (Could not load the default credentials.)
I am trying to deploy firebase functions, but I am receiving an error:

Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.

functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:271
        throw new Error(**'Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.'**);
              ^

After attempting to follow both solutions mentioned in this thread for my first error: Could not load the default credentials? (Node.js Google Compute Engine tutorial)
I am now receiving the following error message:
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied: Consumer 'projects/undefined' has been suspended.
    at callErrorFromStatus (/Users/API/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/secret-manager/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
